# After upgrading the react native version 0.69.0 I got this error

Tags: react-native, native

After upgrading the React Native Version to 0.69.0, I am getting this error while linking react-navigation.

[image]

Comment: how did you upgrade?

Comment: npx react-native upgrade

Comment: from which version?

Comment: 0.68.2 to 0.69.0

Comment: What is your Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version? 
=> 1. classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4") ==> 7.0.4 = Android Gradle Plugin Version, 
=> 2. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip ==> 7.3.3 = Gradle version

Comment: classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow this helper to update rather than react native upgrade :

[Rn helper - 0.68.2 to 0.69](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.2&to=0.69.0)

Some gradle files needs to updated and probably there's something missed.

Do check out and if it stillsa. problem lte me know :)

[image]